# Can I make a route without the action for only one action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

Here's an example of my set up:

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index(int? id) { ... }

  [HttpPost]
  public ActionResult DoSomething(int id) { ... }

  public ActionResult Search([params]) { ... }
}
```

and I want to be able to access them via these routes:

```
/app/User/{id}
/app/User/DoSomething/{id}
/app/User/Search/
```

I tried setting up my routes like this, but then if I try to navigate to `/app/User/Search/` or post to `/app/User/DoSomething/`, the `Index` Action is hit instead.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "UserWithoutIndex",
            url: "User/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

How can I do this? I think it would work to just specify each specific action in it's own route before the `UserWithoutIndex` route above, but I have multiple actions and I don't want to have to create a route specific to each action in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your first route will match any two-segment URL which includes the examples you provided; `/app/User/Search/` and `/app/User/DoSomething/` and the values `Search` and `DoSomething` will be placed in the `id` place holder respectively.  Then because the first route is being matched you are receiving `Index` for the action.  If your `id` will take on some format specifically you could specify a constraint for it in the first route like so:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "UserWithoutIndex",
        url: "User/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "User", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        constraints: new { id = "your regex here" }
    );
```

If you constraint can be specific enough to the format of the `id` than things like `Search` and `DoSomething` won't match and the route won't match so the next route will be tried.

Also, if there will always be an `id` specified in the scenarios where you want the first route to be targeted you should remove the `id = UrlParameter.Optional` default so that way the `id` will be required and the route will ONLY match two-segment URLs because as it is now with the `id` being optional the route will also match one-segment URLs.

Comment: So I could just format the constraint to only accept a number, right?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that.

Comment: Use something like this to match one or more digits `@"\d+"`.

Comment: Thanks! That works pretty well. That is, after all what I wanted - a way to indicate that that route applies when the second segment is an integer. This wouldn't work if my `id` parameter was a string.

Comment: Glad it worked :)  You can create a regex to match strings as well but only if you know the pattern.  You are correct that this might not be ideal if you didn't have any way of distinguishing the values you wanted from those you didn't and in that case I would probably recommend a different approach.